# how to select the id(s) from a table which are contained set of duplicate values(clm1,clm2,cl3)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how to select id=32 and 28 which are contained duplicate    values(product_id,place_id,product_type_id)?

```
id        product_id   place_id    product_type_id  quaty       year      month
22           3           2              1            10         2015       4          
28           6           1              3            10         2015       4          
32           6           1              3            15         2015       5          
33           11          3              6            100        2015       5          
27           30          1              3            13         2015       4
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT id
FROM table1 AS t1
WHERE product_id IN(SELECT product_id
                    FROM table1 AS t2
                    GROUP BY product_id,place_id,product_type_id
                    HAVING COUNT(id) > 1);
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56451/1)

This will give you:

```
| id |
|----|
| 28 |
| 32 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table1 t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table1 t1
                  WHERE t.product_id = t1.product_id AND t.place_id = t1.place_id AND
                        t.product_type_id = t1.product_type_id
                        t.id <> t1.id
                 )
```

Although you can do something similar with `count(*)`, the performance of this query should be much better.  In addition, it can take advantage of an index on `table(product_id, place_id, product_type_id)`.

Answer (score -2):

I hope this helps.

```
SELECT Table1.ID FROM FROM <Table1>
INNER JOIN
(SELECT product_ID, place_id, product_type_id
FROM <Table1> 
Group BY product_ID, place_id, product_type_id
HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1 )a
ON Table1.product_ID = a.product_ID
AND Table1.place_id = a.place_id
AND Table1.product_type_id = a.product_type_id
```